# How to make OneTimeSetup failures fail tests in TeamCity

Tags: nunit, teamcity, nunit-3.0

I have just encountered a scenario where a `TestFixture`'s `OneTimeSetup` method has failed, yet TeamCity has reported all the tests as passed.

I can see in the log that TC is reporting 14 red lines of text, once for each of the 14 tests in the fixture:

> [Step 1/1] OneTimeSetUp:   <...failure text...>

The tests are being run with `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]` attribute, which may be related - I don't know.

At the end of the log, I can see a summary (not in red) summarising again the 14 failures.

> [11:26:48][Step 1/1] Errors and Failures
>
> [11:26:48][Step 1/1]
>
> [11:26:48][Step 1/1] 1) Failed : blah blah blah ...

BUT the build does not fail, and in fact the tests do run successfully.

We are using TeamCity 10.0.2 (build 42234) and "NUnit 3.0" (as per TC setting - we are using 3.2.1 in our actual project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in NUnit 3.2.1, where failures in a `OneTimeSetUp` didn't actually fail the test suite - meaning tools such as TeamCity would have no way to detect the failure.

This was fixed in NUnit 3.4 - upgrading to the latest NUnit should solve your problem. The GitHub issue, for reference: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1379

Comment: ha, unbelievable! Thanks

Comment: For others interested, the problem is with the nunit-console.exe specifically, not with nunit.framework.dll or other components. You need to make sure you don't use ver 3.2.1 of the nunit-console.exe